# Pandas - name data colum from result of count function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code and the aim is to get the data into a dataframe where I can create a bar chart showing the top 10 publishers. Problem is when I do the group by I loose the column name so I cannot select it for the bar chart plot. The pandas rename function requires me to use the name of the colum but it is blank. Is there a way to rename it via index or maybe name it on creation?

```
from itertools import count
from platform import platform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the csv file
data = pd.read_csv("video_game.csv")

#clean the data converting str to numbers where needed + drop unwanted columns
data = data.drop(columns=["NA_players", "EU_players", "JP_players", "Other_players", "Global_players", "User_Count", "Rating", "Critic_Count"])


data['User_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(data['User_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
data['User_Score'] = data['User_Score'].astype(float)

data['Critic_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Critic_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
data['Critic_Score'] = data['Critic_Score'].astype(float)

#select all games and thier publishers with a critic score over 90
data = data[['Publisher','Name', 'Critic_Score']]
data = data.query('Critic_Score >  90')
data = data.groupby(['Publisher']).size().sort_values(ascending = False)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought with it some more and solved it with trail and error. I'm sure there is an easier way but here is the solution for anyone who is interested:

```
from itertools import count
from platform import platform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the csv file
data = pd.read_csv("video_game.csv")

#clean the data converting str to numbers where needed + drop unwanted columns
data = data.drop(columns=["NA_players", "EU_players", "JP_players", "Other_players", "Global_players", "User_Count", "Rating", "Critic_Count"])


data['User_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(data['User_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
data['User_Score'] = data['User_Score'].astype(float)

data['Critic_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Critic_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
data['Critic_Score'] = data['Critic_Score'].astype(float)

#select all games and thier publishers with a critic score over 90
data = data[['Publisher','Name', 'Critic_Score']]
data = data.query('Critic_Score >  90')
data['Count'] = data.groupby('Publisher')['Publisher'].transform('count')
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Publisher'])
data = data[['Publisher', 'Count']]
data = data.sort_values(['Count'], ascending = False)
data = data.head(10)

print(data)
```